# Workaround for Maple in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, maple

I am trying to get the MATLAB toolbox [SOSTOOLS](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/sostools/) to work inside a MATLAB R2010b (7.11.0.584) but get the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> maple at 54 The MAPLE command is not available.

Googling it I found out that MATLAB stopped using Maple at some stage and switched to MuPad.

Short of switching to an older version of MATLAB, is there a known workaround for this situation?

Comment: Could you give some idea about what code returned the error? Was it ones of the demos?

Comment: @TryHard It was sosdemo4

Comment: Best is to contact the authors, otherwise you can try the workaround I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution in the form of installing Maple as the symbolic toolbox engine is not possible with your version of Matlab.

This outlines an alternative possible solution, I did not find a concrete workaround that will spare you work. I recommend you contact the authors, or check for octave versions with the same functionality.

The change to MuPad is a problem that's been posted numerous times, and there is a useful discussion of differences between Maple and MuPad here:
http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=178

For some commands it looks like a simple translator might work. Most of the implementation would apparently be in parsing the output from MuPad and turning it into what Maple would generate. The input to MuPad and Maple is apparently equal most of the time, but read the doc above.

To write a translator, you redirect calls to `maple` by placing in your path the following function `maple` that calls `mupad`:

```
function output=maple(input);
%prepare input here (if necessary) ... 
output=mupad(input);
% parse the output (if necessary) ...
```

More likely than not, a naive call to this re-director will not solve the problem without some input/output parsing.